# Lua/Torch - Rotate a tensor of images

Tags: lua, torch

I would like to rotate a batch of images with size:

```
100  -- num images in batch
3    -- num channels
500  -- image width
500  -- image height
```

Currently, I am able to rotate individual images using the [image library](https://github.com/torch/image/blob/master/doc/simpletransform.md) but it is extremely slow, about 2 seconds per image. Is it possible to efficiently rotate all the images at once?

Comment: I've not used Torch before, so maybe I'm missing something, but couldn't you just do this with ImageMagick or a similar batch-image-processing tool?

Comment: That wouldn't work. I load a dataset of images into memory, but then I want to train a model by giving it random subsamples of those images, i.e. by cropping and randomly rotating them while the program is running.